# having a single controller for all the custom filter in angular ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using custom filter for 5 columns in my ui grid ( angular ui-grid ), link shown below:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_custom_filters

To create a custom filter, a custom modal is created with a controller assigned to it.

This controller is used to creater filter values and filter.term later to be used in main grid filter.

I need to know if we can use a single modal, controller for all 5 columns in my ui-grid.

If someone has already used it, please share.

Comment: Is this on the lines of what you are trying to do? I am not entirely clear on your question (Note: I am not the same Brian). http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes/

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no, this is isn't what I am looking for.If you check the ui grid custom filter implementation, we have a controller where we get filter values and then create filter term based on users selection. I want to use the same controller for creating custom filter for all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it passing the column name in method called from the custom filter template on each column. And then based on the type of column creating the filter options grid.

```
myapp2.controller('BenefitsFilterCtrl', function( $scope, $compile, $timeout ) {
    var $elm;
    $scope.showBenefitsFilter = function(type) {
        $scope.listOfAges = [];

        if(type==='projectId'){
         $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
              if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.projectID ) === -1 ) {
                $scope.listOfAges.push( row.projectID );
              }
            });
        }else if(type==='parameterHeading'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.benefit ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.benefit );
                  }
                });
        }else if(type==='valueParameter'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.benefitSubcategory ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.benefitSubcategory );
                  }
                });
        }else if(type==='benefitType'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.benefitType ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.benefitType );
                  }
                });
        }else if(type==='MatureLevel'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.assessmentMaturityLevel ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.assessmentMaturityLevel );
                  }
                });
        }else if(type==='portfolio'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.oxd ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.oxd );
                  }
                });
        }else if(type==='program'){
             $scope.col.grid.appScope.gridOptions.data.forEach( function (row) {
                  if ( $scope.listOfAges.indexOf( row.program ) === -1 ) {
                    $scope.listOfAges.push( row.program );
                  }
                });
        }
        $scope.listOfAges.sort();
```

Here listOfAges is the options list that can be selected from the grid in the modal.

If anyone encounters similar req, ready to create a plunker and share. As this code snippet is not that desciptive